# How to tell if a UTF-8 file has asian characteres?

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, utf-16, file-io

Question: Is there a simple way to discover if a given UTF file has or does not have not Asian characters? Would be great if that works with both UTF-8 and UTF-16. Better yet if done with ruby instead of a generic algorithm.

EDIT:
By the comments I learn about CJK, that is most likely what I'm looking for.

So, is there a way to test if a UTF file have CJK characters?

Comment: Define Asian characters. Which languages belong and which languages do not?

Comment: I did not downvote, nor did I voted to close, by the way.

Comment: I believe that it's a valid question.

Comment: @sawa ok, thanks for helping me to make my question better instead of downvoting it without comments.

Comment: Now the question looks valid, but for for information, your definition of "Asian Characters" is very arbitrary. No one would call the set of those two languages as Asian languages. There is a set of languages close to that, which is called "East Asian Languages", sometimes abbreated as CJK, which includes Chinese, Japanese, and Korean.

Comment: @sawa actually CJK would work very well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be reinventing the wheel but you can use `unpack('U*')` to get the unicode codepoints from any string. IE

```
   codepoints = '㌂'.unpack('U*').first
    => 13058
```

Then you can use .any?

```
 codepoints.any?{|c| overlaps_cjk?(c)}
```

The overlaps_cjk function you can derive by getting all the desired codepoint blocks you consider "asian characters" from http://graphemica.com/blocks

for instance:

```
 CJK_CODEPOINTS = [(13000..13500)]
 def overlaps_cjk?(codepoint)
   CJK_CODEPOINTS.any?{|range| range.cover?(codepoint)}
 end
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be what I was looking for.